# Find client IP and SOAP call info from a Delphi web service

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap

I have a Delphi Web Server setup and running, publishing Web Services, and I want to know some stuff on the calls to the web services:

- The IP address of the client who calls the web service.
- Some SOAP information on the call, such as username and password.

How can I get this information from within the service code? My class is inheriting from TSoapDataModule, so I figure there's a way to get that info through it. Still, I can't find how.

```
TMyAppServerDataModule = class(TSoapDataModule, ITMyAppServerDataModule ,
            IAppServerSOAP, IAppServer, ITMySOAPWebService)
// ...my working components and methods... //
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get a [TWebRequest](http://docs.codegear.com/docs/radstudio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/HTTPApp_TWebRequest.html) from the Request property of the TWebModule object you get from calling [GetSOAPWebModule](http://docs.codegear.com/docs/radstudio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/WebBrokerSOAP_GetSOAPWebModule.html). TWebRequest will tell you lots of things about the request. Like RemoteAddr

Answer (score 0):

See GetSOAPWebModule.Request (uses WebBrokerSoap;).